# Problems installing steamcmd - unable to locate package lib32gcc1

Tags: debian, steam, bunsenlabs

I'm trying to install steamcmd, but I just get the message  `unable to locate package lib32gcc1` . I'm running BunsenLabs 8.6 (Hydrogen). I've done `sudo apt-get update and upgrade`. I run it on my notebook and am quite rusty at the ins and outs of linux, so I may be missing something simple.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install `lib32gcc1` run the following commands:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install gcc-4.9-base libc6-i386 lib32gcc1
```

Comment: This popped up with some errors (missing files and whatnot), but I was able to install steamcmd regardless. Thank you.